# Фонетика. Слова в транскрипции

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия, фонетический-разбор

1) В слове "следующее" в транскрипции опускается буква "ю"? Это будет выглядеть так [с л' э д у ш' ь j ь] ?

2) В слове "языкознание" два ударения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) В словаре Резниченко (2010 год) для слова ***следующий*** указано произношение *след(ую)щий*, но отмечено, что в беглой речи возможно *(след(у)щий*. Может быть, надо указывать два варианта.

2) В этом же словаре ***языкознание*** имеет одно ударение, ***околоземный*** - два ударения, в слове ***чувственный*** произношение *чу(ст)венный*.

**О дополнительном ударении** [http://wikiredia.ru/wiki/Дополнительное_ударение](http://wikiredia.ru/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Некоторые сложные слова, а также слова с приставками анти-, меж-, около-, контр-, сверх-, супер-, экс- и др. могут иметь, кроме основного, побочное (или второстепенное) ударение. Побочное ударение обычно по порядку бывает первым (ближе к началу слова), а основное — вторым (ближе к концу слова): кля̀твопреступле́ние, самолё̀тострое́ние, о̀колозе́мный, вѝце-президе́нт.

Comment: Значит, при транскрибации "ю" опускается?

Comment: Словарь Резниченко орфоэпический, там говорится о двух вариантах произношения. Я могу предположить, что при транскрибировании нужно указать оба варианта

Answer (score 2):

1) *"Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала XXI века: нормы и её варианты"* (М., 2012), созданный в Институте русского языка им. В.В. Виноградова Российской академии наук под руководством Л.Л. Касаткина, рекомендует такое произношение слова СЛЕ́ДУЮЩИЙ:

**сле́д[уи]щий, след[у]щий** *и допуст*. сле́д[уйу]щий.

Т. е. вариант с прочтением буквы ***ю*** в этом слове как [йу] – наименее предпочтительный из трёх возможных.

2) Побочное ударение в слове **языкозна́ние** отсутствует.

Answer (score 1):

1. Буква ю может обозначать два звука: либо ['у] (после мягких согласных), либо [j'у] (после мягкого знака или в начале слова). При транскрибировании она не используется. Верная транскрипция: [с л' э́ д у j' у ш̅ ' ь j' ь].
2. Нет, ударение одно: языкозна́ние [j' ъ з ы^э к ʌ з н а́ н' ь j' ь]. В русском языке дополнительное ударение, как правило, стоит перед основным, так что едва ли оно вообще возможно в этом слове.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, почему тогда в слове "здравствуй"  буква "в" опускается в транскрипции, а в слове "следующий" буква "ю" нет? Мы же в речи говорим не "следующий", а "следущий"

Comment: И ещё один вопрос: в слове "четырёхъярусный" два ударения?

Comment: @Alena это два отдельных вопроса — задайте же их отдельно! Я отвечу )

Comment: Aer: _В русском языке дополнительное ударение, как правило, стоит перед основным, так что едва ли оно вообще возможно в этом слове_. (???) === С первой частью этого предложения согласен. Но как из неё вытекает вторая: "... **так что** едва ли оно вообще возможно в этом слове"? Ведь если бы побочное ударение в слове _языкознание_ имело место, оно бы находилось именно в первом корне, т. е. **перед** основным ударением.

Comment: @slava1947 я считаю, что произношение ЯзыкознАние, или язЫкознАние, или языкОзнАние (прописные буквы — ударные) вычурно и невероятно в нормальной речевой ситуации. Так что действительно дополнительное ударение, возникающее в РЯ лишь в предударных слогах, в данном слове невозможно.